# The MetaMask Web3 object error for a Web App that does not have web3 or ethereum js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, web3js, metamask

I have a web app which runs in GCP. It's built using GraphQL, Nodejs, Reactjs, Redux.

For some customers, I can see that they are unable to perform any post-call to my backend API. They receive the following error:

> The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like
>   eth_mining without a callback parameter

I am not having anything related to Ethereum or web3 in my app. However, I can see that the customers who are getting those errors have MetaMask chrome extension installed.

I am not sure how to get rid of this error or how to give a workaround for those users who get this error, other than asking them to try in Incognito.

Full Error Stack Trace:

> Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods
>   like eth_mining without a callback parameter. See
>   https://github.com/MetaMask/faq/blob/master/DEVELOPERS.md#dizzy-all-async---think-of-metamask-as-a-light-client
>   for details. at MetamaskInpageProvider._sendSync
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:82782)
>   at MetamaskInpageProvider.send
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:81748)
>   at Proxy.t.send
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:694)
>   at a.send
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:190679)
>   at w.mining
>   (chrome-extension://nkbihfbeogaeaoehlefnkodbefgpgknn/inpage.js:1:189926)